# How do i Include a fraction of zend framework to laravel?

Tags: php, zend-framework, laravel

Ok what i want to do is use Zend Translate adapter only because i already have 5 language csv's in zend -understandable format.
and i just want to:

```
 echo $translate->_('word_to_translate'); //from zend adapter
```

from the view in the views/ folder
i am using blade as main.blade.php and trying to call $translate
which is defined as:

```
/*
 * Zend_Translate
 */
define('APP_PATH',  getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/members');
define('APP_LANG',  APP_PATH . '/lang');

require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';

$translate = new Zend_Translate( array( 
'adapter' => 'csv', 
'content' => APP_LANG, 
'scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY ) );
$translate->setLocale($locale);
```

$locale is defined earlier is the language

what i tried is to include and initiate everything statically from various locations but that didn't work.
Maybe i need to create a facade i think but with the zend method inside and is getting 
difficult.

i read all documents about making a facade but what i didn't understand is if it has to be done with composer in mind so it can generate the autoloader classes, or i can do it mannually

Answer (score 1):

As Zend Framework is modular, this is simple (assuming ZF1, for ZF2 you'll use `Zend\ObjectName` instead because it uses namespaces):

1. Add the Zend Framework library folder to your `include_path` in `php.ini`.
2. Create a Zend_Translate object like so:

   ```
   $translator = new Zend_Translate( ...options... );
   ```
3. Translate text, like this:

   ```
   echo $translator->_('Hello world');
   ```

Full documentation for `Zend_Translate` can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.html).